# How to create RollOver Effects in JS?

Tags: javascript

Ive seen buttons in html have RollOver effects but what else can you add this effect too ?

Comment: Any element webpage can have a rollover effect, would it be from Javascript or CSS. What about you google "html mouse events"?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mouseover event handler to any element in a page.  The important part is what you do once the event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Like zneak said in comments, pretty much anything.  Set code in the onmouseover event of an HTML element.

A couple of elements can have rollover effects set through css pseudoclasses (for example, a:hover for an anchor tag), but it's limited and not 100% warranted across all browsers.